# Python. Отправить POST запрос со строкой на русском языке

Tags: python, xml, requests, utf-8

Пытаюсь отправить post запрос

```
r = requests.post(api_server, data=xml, auth=(api_key, api_token))
```

В переменной xml лежит что-то наподобе:

```
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <request>
            <description>{}</description>
        </request>""".format('Тест')
```

при отправке post запроса получаю ошибку

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 237-240: Body ('Тест') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.
```

Пытался вместо 'Тест' отправлять `'Тест'.encode('utf-8')`.
Всё отрабатывало без ошибок, но результат запроса оставался в кодировке и разумеется был нечитабелен. Вопрос в следующем: Как мне отправить post запрос, у которого в data будет строка на русском языке?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно кодировать не конкретную строку, а весь набор данных, то есть

```
r = requests.post(api_server, data=xml.encode('utf-8'), auth=(api_key, api_token))
```